# Add where to the SUM in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a EF query:

```
var result = unitOfWork.deviceInstanceRepository.Get()
          .GroupBy(w => new
          {
              DeviceId = w.DeviceId,
              CatalogName = w.Device.CatalogNo,
              DeviceName = w.Device.Name,
              ManufacturerName = w.Device.Manufacturer1.Name,
          })
          .Select(s => new InstancesSummary
          {
              DeviceId = s.Key.DeviceId,
              CatalogNo = s.Key.CatalogName,
              DeviceName = s.Key.DeviceName,
              DeviceManufacturer = s.Key.ManufacturerName,
              Quantity = s.Sum(x => x.Quantity)
          }).ToList();
```

At the moment it returns a distinct list of objects with their `Count` from the database. But I want to modify this query to get the number of devices connected with eg. user 1 and 2.

I know that I can do it by adding this:

```
 List<Expression<Func<DeviceInstance, bool>>> where = new List<Expression<Func<DeviceInstance, bool>>>();
        where.Add(w => w.DeviceUsage.UserId == 1);
```

for user 1, and changing this line:

```
 var result = unitOfWork.deviceInstanceRepository.Get(where)
```

but in this solution I need to make two queries.

Is there any way to make something like this:

```
Quantity = s.Sum(x => x.Quantity).Where(w=>w.DeviceUsage.UserId==1)
```

to get sum of devices connected with user 1 and same to user 2?

@Updated with `DevinceInstance` class:

```
public partial class DeviceInstance
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int DeviceId { get; set; }
    public string SerialNo { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ProjectId { get; set; }
    public bool Issue { get; set; }
    public string IssueDetails { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public virtual Device Device { get; set; }
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
    public virtual DeviceUsage DeviceUsage { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this one:

```
Quantity = s.Where(w=>w.DeviceUsage.UserId==1 || w.DeviceUsage.UserId==2) 
            .Sum(x => x.Quantity);
```

Comment: Ugh sorry to tell But I was testing code above with my `where expression` ( I forgot to remove it.  When I removed it I got NullReferenceException from your code :(

Comment: @szpic so you tested it and it didn't work. correct?

Comment: Yes.  Those two `Where` throws `NullReferenceException`

Comment: Could you please post the definition of s's type? Thanks !

Comment: I updated question. Hope I pasted you were asking for.

Comment: Yeah, I think you did. Please let me check it out and I will be back asap.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58162/discussion-between-christos-and-szpic).